# Wocoomerce single product - variation dropdown replaces image only for color variation

Tags: php, woocommerce

When testing a single product, and using the dropdown to change a variation, the image of the selected variation changes only if the product's variations are color variations.

[image]

When the product's variations are something other than color variations, you can use the dropdown and the description changes accordingly, but the image attached to each variation doesn't change.

I tried to tweak the file woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php but it didn't work. The code responsible for the image variation:

The relevant code in the file:

```
echo '<ul class="nav d-none">';
 foreach ($options as $option) {
 echo '<li class="nav-item">';
 echo '<a href="#'.$option.'" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link color-attribute"  data-color="'.$option.'" title="" ></a>';
echo '</li>';
    }
```

echo '';

When disabling the a tag in the code the image stops changing also for color variations, but I don't know why it's only working for color variations.

Any ideas?